# Help with Dual problem in SDP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

I'm having a problem to find the Dual of a Semidefinite programing problem:

$$\min\;\;(tr(U)+tr(V))/2$$

$$s.t.\;\; \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 U & X \\
X^T & V
\end{array} \right]\succeq0$$

$$X_{ij}=M_{ij}\;\;(i,j)\in\Omega$$

Where $tr()$ is the trace operator, $U, V$ and $X$ are the matrix variables of the problem and $M$ is a given matrix.

It is known that a general SDP has the followind Primal Dual pair:

$$P) \;\; \min \;\; tr(C^TX)$$

$$s.t.\;\; tr(A_{i}^TX)=b_i\;\;i=1,...,m$$
$$X\succeq 0$$

$$D)\;\; \max b^Ty$$

$$s.t.\;\; \sum_{i=1}^{m}A_iy_i + S = C $$
$$S\succeq0$$

But i can't find the way to modify my problem to this form.

Comment: Make $S$ a block diagonal matrix with the matrix of your problem as the first block, and $\pm (X_{ij} - M_{ij})$ as the other blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to transform everything into the standard form. Writing the primal problem in the standard form is easy. In fact, we can set

$$ C = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 I/2 & 0 \\
0 & I/2
\end{array} \right], A_k = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1_{ij}/2 \\
1_{ji}/2 & 0
\end{array} \right], b_k = M_{ij}, \forall (i,j) \in \Omega.$$

Therefore, the dual will be
$$ \max ~ tr(Y, M) $$
$$ s.t. ~ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 I/2 & -Y/2 \\
-Y^\top/2 & I/2
\end{array} \right] \succeq 0$$
where $M$ is a matrix whose elements are zero if $(i,j) \notin \Omega$ otherwise $M_{ij}$.