# Solving simple SDP by hand

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I am trying to understand how to solve the following simple semidefinite program by hand.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x_{11}\\ \text{subject to} & 2 x_{12} = 1\\ & \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12}\\
x_{12} & x_{22} \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0\end{array}$$

I have figured out that in the standard formulation we have

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{tr} \left( C X \right)\\ \text{subject to} & \mbox{tr} \left( A X \right) = b\\ & X \succeq 0\end{array}$$

where

$$ C = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\
0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$ and $$ A =  \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 &1\\
1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$ and $ b = 1$

However, I have no idea how to proceed from there. Any pointers?

Comment: You mean $ Trace( AX ) $, right?

Comment: No, $ tr(C \cdot X)$ is correct.

Comment: I meant this for the constraint. Instead of $ A X = b $, it should $ Tr (A X) = b $.

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: This helps? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982336/help-with-dual-problem-in-sdp?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Because of the restriction we get  $ X = \left( \begin{array}{cc} x_{11} & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & x_{22} \end{array} \right)$ and therefore $x_{11}x_{22} - 1/4 \geq 0 $ because $X$ is positive semidefinite. This is the solution for the primal form. 
However I have no idea how to calculate the solution for the dual form.

Comment: You forgot the diagonal entries. The constraint $X \succeq 0$ encapsulates $2^2 - 1 = 3$ inequality constraints, namely, $x_{11} \geq 0$, $x_{22} \geq 0$ and $\det (X) \geq 0$ (which you have considered already).

Comment: Why do you need the dual?

Comment: Is the reason you're trying to calculate the solution in dual form to provide a certificate that you have indeed found the optimal solution? Strong duality only holds for SDPs under certain conditions.

Comment: But note that for your particular problem, you can't actually achieve the optimal value i.e. there is no minimum value - only an infimum, and you can show this using the inequalities implied by the fact that a feasible $X$ has to be psd.